# Meaning of computing the tensor product of vectors

Tags: definition, tensor-products, tensors

In a nutshell: a proposition in Abraham's *Foundations of Mechanics* states that, given a vector space $E$ with basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$, the space $T^r_s(E)$ of tensors of type $(r,s)$, the dual basis $\alpha^1,\ldots,\alpha^n$, we have that
$$\{ e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_r}\otimes\alpha^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\alpha^{j_s} : i_k,j_k = 1,\ldots,n\}$$
is a basis of $T^r_s(E)$.

I'm immediately confused as the tensor product is defined between tensors, and $e_{i_1},\ldots,e_{i_r}$ are vectors, not tensors. **What is the meaning of the above set then?**

---

The proposition (and its proof, in case that helps):

[image]

Comment: A vector is a $(1,0)$ tensor.

Comment: @K.defaoite could you explain how?

Comment: It is very cheap to explain what $\otimes$ is by simply saying that it is nothing else than the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of the vector components. Books that omit that pedagogical part should not be read.

Comment: @KurtG. It's very useful for someone just learning about tensors. However, not every book is written with them in mind. "Should not be read first" is more correct IMO.

Comment: @Arthur I agree. It was a bit of a provocation. The book has in mind as "basic" audience "mathematicians, physicists and engineers interested in geometrical methods in mechanics  assuming, a background in calculus, linear algebra, some classical analysis and point set topology."  When it was published in 1967 I was only two years old and cannot comment on the knowledge one could assume of that audience about $\otimes$ at that time.

Comment: Correction: published 1978.

Comment: @KurtG that seems relevant to know, but I'm still not sure what the meaning of $e_i$ in the tensor product of the excerpt means.

Comment: $e_i$ and $e_j$ are basis vectors of $E\,.$ The author assumes dim$E=n$. So: please take $E=\mathbb R^n$ choose your favourite basis, and write out the Kronecker product $e_i\otimes e_j$ in components of those basis vectors. Best to edit the question to do so. We will then check. (This is a very important mission. Engineers in 1978 could not have been that much smarter than we are today. :) )

Comment: @Sam Where are you learning about tensors? Have you not seen something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3942678/mathematical-properties-of-rank-n-tensors-where-n2/3947326#3947326) ?

Answer (score 1):

$v \in E$ is naturally associated to $V \in T^1_0(E)$ via $V(\alpha) = \alpha(v)$ for all $\alpha \in E^*$, and $\alpha \in E^*$ is by definition an element of $T^0_1(E)$ since $v \mapsto \alpha(v)$ is a linear map that takes in a vector and produces a scalar.

The text is implicitly making these identifications and then applying the already defined tensor product of $T^r_s(E)$.